# How to send data via HTTP request to Firestore database

Tags: node.js, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So, I am trying to make an app with Node.js, Vue, and Firebase. I currently have a very basic function using firebase functions to send data to the realtime database via http request. I cant figure out how to do the same for Firestore database.

My goal is to send data or a file of some JSON data to my Firestore database from outside the app with an HTTP request. I know how to deploy functions I just am not sure how to send files or JSON to the database for further use.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I have been playing around with different functions but can't seem to figure it out. I have looked at many of the docs/videos for firebase but I am pretty knew to this and can't quite grasp it.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp() //need admin sdk

const toUpperCase = (string) => string.toUpperCase();

exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
const text = request.query.text;

const secretText = toUpperCase(text);

admin
    .database()
    .ref('/sentMSG')
    .push({ text: secretText })
    .then(() =>
        response.json({
            message: 'great!!!!',
            text
        })
    )
    .catch(() => {
        response.json({
            message: 'not great :^('
        });
    });
});

exports.writeToStore = functions.firestore.https.onRequest((request, 
response) => {
  let data = request.query.text
  let setDoc = db.collection('cities').doc('LA').set(data)
   .then(() =>
        response.json({
            message: 'great!!!!',
            text
        })
    )
    .catch(() => {
        response.json({
            message: 'not great :^('
        });
    });
});
```

The addMessage function adds data to realtime database but I need to do it for Firestore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**index.js**

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const _ = require('lodash');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
let data = req.query.data;

  try {
          await db.collection('users').doc().set({ userId: data });
        } catch(err) { res.send(JSON.stringify(err)) }

      res.send('Success');
})

app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  let payload = req.body;
  let keys = Object.keys(payload);
  let obj = {};
  let i = 0;

  try {
    _.forEach(payload, async data => {
      obj[keys[i]] = data;
      i++;
    })

   await db.collection('users').doc().set(obj);
  } catch(err) { res.send(JSON.stringify(err))}

    res.send('Success');
})

exports.writeToFirestore = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

You can then call this Cloud Function like such: `linkToURL/writeToFirestore?data=5` or make a Post request to `linkURL/writeToFirestore`

---

From what I understand, whenever the Cloud Function is triggered, you want to write data in both the Firebase Realtime Database and in Firestore. Cloud Function will only execute one function in the `exports` object. In this case, since the function is being triggered by HTTPS, you can create a single `exports.writeToBoth` that encapsulates the code to write in Realtime DB and Firestore. Furthermore, I noticed that the writeToFirestore written is invalid, you need to change `functions.firestore.https.onRequest` to `functions.https.onRequest`.

In any case, you can refer to this code as a base, should you want:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

let writeToFirestore = data => {
  let setDoc = db.collection('users').doc('0').set(data);
} 

let writeToRealtimeDB = data => {
  // ...
 // Your code
 // ...
}

exports.writeToBoth = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  let data = req.query.text;

  // Write to both DB
try {
  writeToFirestore(data);
  writeToRealtimeDB(data);
} catch(err) { res.send('Error') } 

  res.send('Success');
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much for replying, I have been stuck for a few days now. When I put in your code and deploy it it is fine. But when I go to send the HTTP request I get an error. How am I supposed to send the information?
As a test I just put in the http request link, we'll say https://functionTestLink/writeToBoth?text=sampleRandomString here ...

Do I just put the data I want to send after the link like I did?    
  "?text=sampleRandomString"
I just want to get any information at this point to my firestore database. I don't even want to use realtime but it was the only thing I could get to work

Comment: No problem, what error did you get? I suggest giving this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request) a read. Essentially, if you make a request like `functionTestLink/writeToBoth?text=sample`, you can extract `sample` from Cloud Functions like such: `req.query.text`. Furthermore, if you want to go up a notch, you can instead make a `POST` request and supply a json object which will be accessible from `req.body`. For example, consider this cURL request:

Comment: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" functionTestLink/writeToBoth -d '{"text":"sample", "extra": "0a"}'` In your Cloud Functions, you can then extract the data payload using `req.body.text` and `req.body.extra`, which can then be passed to the writeToFirestore function

Comment: By error I just mean that the function returns Error from the code. I have read that doc but I am very new to all of this and don't have much help available. Is there anyway I could bother you to help me write the most basic function that accepts text or JSON object and puts it into my firestore. I am looking for a place to start off and grow from there but I just can't seem to get off the ground. To summarize I need to get data from outside the application and send it to firestore. What is the most basic function to get say the word "sample" from the url box to my firestore database.

Comment: I have no experience with curl. Should I learn curl or can I do without? Thanks again. I truly appreciate any help.

Comment: Sure, no problem I'll create a basic function that writes to Firestore and I will explain from there. Regarding cURL, it's not a must per se, but it is useful. Alternatively, you can use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/) to make API requests for you. You can even use Chrome DevTools from `Inspect Element` and write a `POST` request there using the native `[Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Give me some time to create a basic function and then we can look at it and examine it line by line.

Comment: You are a saint! Take all the time you need.

Comment: I uploaded a repo on [Github](https://github.com/JKleinne/clooud-functions-firestore) which you can run out-of-the-box, assuming you have the firebase-cli installed, by running `firebase deploy`. Alright so you have to options here: passing data to `/writeToFirestore?data=asd` using query strings, but with the way the code was made, you can only pass data to a query string named `data` but you can modify it so that it fetches any query string you pass. The second option, **my recommendation** allows you to handle `POST` requests to the `writeToFirestore` endpoint. Basically,

Comment: Download Postman and we'll go through this step-by-step. Once downlaoded, you'll see `GET` followed buy a textbox where you can write a URL. Change the `GET` to a `POST` and paste your Cloud Function link `stuff.../writeToFirestore` in the link URL box. Then, in the bottom of that box, click "Body", then check the "raw" radio button and on its right, change "Text" to "JSON (application/json)", then just write a json object like `{
 "stuff": "asdwae",
 "numbers": "321415",
 "extra": "ewad"
}`. Finally click Send. This will make a POST request to the function and post the JSON obj to firesto

Comment: Alternatively, you can simply run a cURL command in terminal or command line like such `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" functionTestLink/writeToFirestore -d '{"text":"sample", "extra": "0a"}'` which will store the argument you passed to `-d` in the Firestore

Comment: and don't forget to run `npm install` in the `/functions/` folder!

Comment: okay! I used postman like you said and it added it to my firebase! Thanks so much. This code works perfectly but I dont quite understand the logic. You have added a bunch of stuff I haven't seen before in other docs/videos Ive seen. At the very least even if you don't want to babysit me anymore I totally get it and I am SUPER appreciative!

Comment: Hey no worries, glad everything worked out for you! I don't mind at all in helping, I was once in your shoes and some kind soul also helped me figure things out. I guess this is my way of giving back :) . In any case, if you have twitter, you can message me any time and I'll answer whenever I can. I'm gonna be busy in the following minutes, but I'll respond once everything's dealt with! You can find my Twitter in my profile page